# copying table with data from different database in Microsoft SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

I am writing store procedure for data migration. In there, I need to copy the table and its whole data from other database to current database's temp table. But, database name will come as a parameter. And then I need to process that copied data. But, I do not know how to make it with dynamic database name.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[MGRT] 
   @DBName VARCHAR(50)
 AS
BEGIN
   SET NOCOUNT ON;
   IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#TMPCH') IS NOT NULL               
      DROP TABLE #TMPCH;            
   SELECT * INTO #TMPCH FROM MDDX.dbo.CH ORDER BY MDate,Mtime               

DECLARE @count INT = 0              
DECLARE @curRow INT = 0             
SELECT @count = COUNT(*) FROM #TMPCH                

WHILE @curRow <= @count             
    BEGIN           
        DECLARE @lastDate NVARCHAR(10) = '-'        
        SET @lastDate = (SELECT TOP 1 To_Date FROM CH ORDER BY SysKey DESC)     

        IF @lastDate = '' OR @lastDate IS NULL      
            BEGIN   
                SET @lastDate = '-'
                PRINT @lastDate
            END 

        INSERT INTO CH(syskey,CurCode,CurDesc,CurSymbol,CurRate,From_Date,To_Date,userid,username)      
            (SELECT @curRow,CurCode,CurDesc,CurSymbol,CURRATE,@lastDate,MDate,'admin','Administrator'   
             FROM (SELECT *,ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY MDate,MTime) AS rowNo FROM #TMPCH) AS TMP WHERE rowNo = @curRow) 
        SET @curRow = @curRow + 1       
    END         
END
```

I need to use @DBName instead of MDDX in getting data.

Thank you!

Comment: You can use dynamic query. Show what you have tried so far.

Comment: That's just sample. In real, I need to calculate more like that. Thank u!

Answer (score 0):

You will need to use a dynamic query, as follows;

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[MGRT] 
   @DBName VARCHAR(50)
 AS
BEGIN
   SET NOCOUNT ON;
   DECLARE sSQL as varchar(200)

   IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#TMPCH') IS NOT NULL               
      DROP TABLE #TMPCH;            

  sSQL = 'SELECT * INTO #TMPCH FROM @DBName.dbo.CH ORDER BY MDate,Mtime'               
  Exec (sSQL)

DECLARE @count INT = 0              
DECLARE @curRow INT = 0             
SELECT @count = COUNT(*) FROM #TMPCH                

WHILE @curRow <= @count             
    BEGIN           
        DECLARE @lastDate NVARCHAR(10) = '-'        
        SET @lastDate = (SELECT TOP 1 To_Date FROM CH ORDER BY SysKey DESC)     

        IF @lastDate = '' OR @lastDate IS NULL      
            BEGIN   
                SET @lastDate = '-'
                PRINT @lastDate
            END 

        INSERT INTO CH(syskey,CurCode,CurDesc,CurSymbol,CurRate,From_Date,To_Date,userid,username)      
            (SELECT @curRow,CurCode,CurDesc,CurSymbol,CURRATE,@lastDate,MDate,'admin','Administrator'   
             FROM (SELECT *,ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY MDate,MTime) AS rowNo FROM #TMPCH) AS TMP WHERE rowNo = @curRow) 
        SET @curRow = @curRow + 1       
    END         
END
```